# How to send USDT using Web3.php

Tags: erc-20, usdt, web3.php

i am trying to send USDT using the ERC20 address . But not able to do. Can anyone please guide me how to do ..Here is the steps
Step 1:
use Web3\Contract;
$contractAddress = 'ERC-20 contract deployed address'
$contract = new Contract('http://localhost:8545', $abi);
$contractInstance = $contract->at($contractAddress);

Step 2:

```
$amount = 100, $receiver = 'Receiver addresss'
```

Step 3:

```
$contractInstance->call(transfer, [$amount, $receiver], $callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to be able to help you as I fixed this a few days ago.

```
const sendERC20Transaction = async (receiver, amount) => {
    var Tx     = require('ethereumjs-tx')
    const Web3 = require('web3')
    const web3 = new Web3('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/your-project-id')
    web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add('privateKey of fromwallet');
    var contractAbi =[];
    var tokenAddress = '0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7'//Tether token(USDT)
    var fromAddress = '0x3df...'
    var tokenInst = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi,tokenAddress);
    tokenInst.methods.transfer(receiver, amounts).send({from: fromAddress, gas: 100000},function (error, result){ //get callback from function which is your transaction key
        if(!error){
            console.log(result);
            handleSuccessTrue();
        } else{
            console.log(error);
            web3.eth.getBalance(fromAddress, (err,bal) => { alert('Your account has ' + web3.utils.fromWei(bal, 'ether') + ', Insufficient funds for gas * price + value on your wallet')});
            handleSuccessFalse();
        }
    });
//Finally, you can check if usdt tranaction success through this code.
tokenInst.methods.balanceOf(receiver).call().then(console.log)
.catch(console.error);
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: You are using the API from https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/your-project-id ..I installed the Ethereum node on my Server. I am able to generate address there ..Able to send transaction from there.. Is it possible to to do with it??

Comment: This isn't php though.

Comment: This is not web3.php. This is for web3.js